# Deploying a Pyramid application using uWSGI and Cherokee

Tags: python, pyramid, web-deployment, cherokee

I'm attempting to setup a generic Pyramid project to work with uWSGI through Cherokee, but constantly get a "no app loaded" error. All the research I've done doesn't really give me much to go on. Anyone have any ideas? Please note that I 'am' using a virtualenv via virtualenvwrapper.

This is from my development.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:2626
master = true
processes = 1
virtualenv = /home/user/.virtualenvs/pyramid/
pythonpath = /home/user/Projects/ConventionMeStatic
```

And this is the command I've been trying to use to launch it: `/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini development.ini --plugin python`.

I can post any further details but there have been no other changes made to the project itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified a virtualenv and a pytonpath, but you have not specified which app to load.

If you have a single-file app you can load that file with the --wsgi-file option, if you have a deployment.ini file you can use the --paste option as described here

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/UsePaste

or the --ini-paste shortcuts described in examples section of the uwsgi wiki

Comment: That's a very true statement. The confusing thing however is that every guide I've seen so far hasn't either. It seems that it might be a weird version of uWsgi as it returns 'uwsgi: unrecognized option '--paste'. For reference it's Ubuntu 12.04 fully updated.

Comment: be sure to put the --plugin option before the --paste one